# Terraform local_file inconsistent final plan

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file

I am using `local_file` to generate ansible inventory from template like this:

**ansible.hosts**

```
[workers]
%{ for worker in workers ~}
${worker.name} ansible_host=${worker.private_ip} ansible_user=${ssh_user}
%{ endfor ~}
```

**Resource definition**

```
resource "local_file" "ansible_inventory" {
  count = 1

  filename ="${path.cwd}/ansible.hosts"
  content  = templatefile(
    "${path.module}/templates/ansible/ansible.hosts", {
      workers               = var.workers
    })
}
```

When I resize infrastructure one worker is removed , than I apply and terraform crashes with:

**log**

```
When expanding the plan for module.provisioner.local_file.ansible_inventory[0]
to include new values learned so far during apply, provider
"registry.terraform.io/-/local" produced an invalid new value for .content:

was cty.StringVal("[workers]\n
shswarm-worker-0-saving-wombat ansible_host=*.*.*.1 ansible_user=centos\n\n
shswarm-gpu-worker-0-superb-sculpin ansible_host=*.*.*.2 ansible_user=centos"),

but now cty.StringVal("[workers]\n
shswarm-worker-0-saving-wombat ansible_host=*.*.*.1 ansible_user=centos")

This is a bug in the provider, which should be reported in the provider's own
issue tracker.
```

After terraform plan file content is changed because one worker node is removed.

**Is there any way to fix that ?**

I commented on related github issue:
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-local/issues/79

Comment: What is `var.workers`?

Comment: workers are array of aws ec2 instances. ===>

workers = [for worker in aws_instance.worker : {
    id         = worker.id,
    name       = worker.tags.Name,
    public_ip  = worker.public_ip,
    private_ip = worker.private_ip
  }]

Comment: This would probably be easier if you used the JSON or YAML formats for Ansible inventories, because there are intrinsic Terraform functions to support this, and you would not need to rely so much on the templating engine and the `local` provider.

Comment: How can I pass ansible json or yaml without writing it on disk first ?